# Code reusability issue when creating API with Flask

Tags: python, flask, design-patterns, reusability, maintenance-plan

I have code reusability issue in my code, this is one of example of routes folder file, it's users.py:

```
from models import User, ApiResponse
from mongoengine import ValidationError
from flask import request
from utils import get_timestamp
from copy import deepcopy
from authentication import check_password_hash, generate_password_hash, tokenizer, detokenizer, get_data_by_token
from validation import is_identity_valid, is_role_valid
from env import ENV


def create_user():
  try:
    # Authentication check
    auth = request.cookies.get('auth')  # type: ignore
    if auth is None:
      return ApiResponse(401, 'fail', 'Unauthorized, auth is none.', None)
    data = get_data_by_token(str(auth))
    if data is None:
      return ApiResponse(401, 'fail', 'Unauthorized, token is none.', None)
    user, newToken = data
    if user is None:
      return ApiResponse(401, 'fail', 'Unauthorized, user is none.', None)
    if not str(user.role) in ['admin']:
      return ApiResponse(403, 'fail', 'Previlege is forbidden.', None)

    # Get timestamp
    # 1683478800000 adalah timestamp proyek ini dimulai
    timestamp = get_timestamp()

    body = request.json
    if body:
      userReq = User(**body['data'])  # JSON deserialize

      if not is_identity_valid(str(userReq.identity)):
        return ApiResponse(400, 'fail', 'Invalid identity.', None)

      if not is_role_valid(str(userReq.role)):
        print(userReq.role)
        return ApiResponse(400, 'fail', 'Invalid role.', None)

      # Mencari user yang ada di database
      userDbList = User.objects(identity=userReq.identity)  # type: ignore
      if len(userDbList) != 0:
        return ApiResponse(409, 'fail', 'User already exists.', None)

      userReq._id = timestamp
      userReq.password = generate_password_hash(str(userReq.password))
      userReq.save()

      resp = ApiResponse(
          201, 'success', 'User created successfully.', userReq.to_mongo())
      if newToken:
        resp.set_cookie('auth', newToken, path=ENV.API_ENDPOINT)
      return resp
    else:
      return ApiResponse(400, 'fail', 'Bad request.', None)
  except ValidationError:
    return ApiResponse(422, 'fail', 'Unprocessable entity.', None)
  except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    return ApiResponse(500, 'fail', 'Internal server error.', None)


def get_users():
  try:
    # Authentication check
    auth = request.cookies.get('auth')  # type: ignore
    if auth is None:
      return ApiResponse(401, 'fail', 'Unauthorized, auth is none.', None)
    data = get_data_by_token(str(auth))
    if data is None:
      return ApiResponse(401, 'fail', 'Unauthorized, token is none.', None)
    user, newToken = data
    if user is None:
      return ApiResponse(401, 'fail', 'Unauthorized, user is none.', None)
    if not str(user.role) in ['admin']:
      return ApiResponse(403, 'fail', 'Previlege is forbidden.', None)

    users = User.objects().all()  # type: ignore
    userList = [user.to_mongo() for user in users]
    resp = ApiResponse(
        200, 'success', 'Users retrieved successfully.', userList)
    resp.set_cookie('auth', newToken, path=ENV.API_ENDPOINT)
    return resp
  except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    return ApiResponse(500, 'fail', 'Internal server error.', None)


def get_user(user_id):
  try:

    # Authentication check
    auth = request.cookies.get('auth')  # type: ignore
    if auth is None:
      return ApiResponse(401, 'fail', 'Unauthorized, auth is none.', None)
    data = get_data_by_token(str(auth))
    if data is None:
      return ApiResponse(401, 'fail', 'Unauthorized, token is none.', None)
    user, newToken = data
    if user is None:
      return ApiResponse(401, 'fail', 'Unauthorized, user is none.', None)

    # Admin check
    if not str(user.role) in ['admin']:
      if int(user._id) != int(user_id):  # type: ignore
        print(int(user._id), int(user_id))  # type: ignore
        return ApiResponse(403, 'fail', 'Forbidden.', None)

    userList = User.objects(_id=int(user_id))  # type: ignore
    if len(userList) == 0:
      return ApiResponse(404, 'fail', 'User not found.', None)
    userReq = userList[0]

    resp = ApiResponse(
        200, 'success', 'User retrieved successfully.', userReq.to_mongo())
    resp.set_cookie('auth', newToken, path=ENV.API_ENDPOINT)

    return resp
  except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    return ApiResponse(500, 'fail', 'Internal server error.', None)


def put_user(user_id):
  try:

    # Authentication check
    auth = request.cookies.get('auth')  # type: ignore
    if auth is None:
      return ApiResponse(401, 'fail', 'Unauthorized, auth is none.', None)
    data = get_data_by_token(str(auth))
    if data is None:
      return ApiResponse(401, 'fail', 'Unauthorized, token is none.', None)
    user, newToken = data
    if user is None:
      return ApiResponse(401, 'fail', 'Unauthorized, user is none.', None)

    # Admin check
    isAdmin = True
    if not str(user.role) in ['admin']:
      if int(user._id) != int(user_id):  # type: ignore
        return ApiResponse(403, 'fail', 'Forbidden.', None)
      isAdmin = False

    userList = User.objects(_id=int(user_id))  # type: ignore
    if len(userList) == 0:
      return ApiResponse(404, 'fail', 'User not found.', None)
    userOld = userList[0]

    body = request.json
    if body:
      oldUser = deepcopy(userOld)
      newUser = User(**body['data'])

      # Field update
      if newUser.password is not None:
        userOld.password = generate_password_hash(str(newUser.password))

      if is_role_valid(str(newUser.role)) and isAdmin:
        userOld.role = str(newUser.role)

      userOld.save()
      response = {
          'old_data': oldUser.to_mongo(),
          'new_data': userOld.to_mongo()
      }
      resp = ApiResponse(200, 'success', 'User updated succesfully.', response)
      resp.set_cookie('auth', newToken, path=ENV.API_ENDPOINT)
      return resp
    else:
      return ApiResponse(400, 'fail', 'Bad request.', None)
  except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    return ApiResponse(500, 'fail', 'Internal server error.', None)


def delete_user(user_id):
  try:
    # Authentication check
    auth = request.cookies.get('auth')  # type: ignore
    if auth is None:
      return ApiResponse(401, 'fail', 'Unauthorized, auth is none.', None)
    data = get_data_by_token(str(auth))
    if data is None:
      return ApiResponse(401, 'fail', 'Unauthorized, token is none.', None)
    user, newToken = data
    if user is None:
      return ApiResponse(401, 'fail', 'Unauthorized, user is none.', None)

    # Admin check
    if not str(user.role) in ['admin']:
      return ApiResponse(403, 'fail', 'Forbidden.', None)

    # Fetch the user from the collection based on the provided ID
    userList = User.objects(_id=int(user_id))  # type: ignore

    # Check if user found
    if len(userList) == 0:
      return ApiResponse(404, 'fail', 'User not found.', None)
    userReq = userList[0]

    # Remove from database
    userReq.delete()

    resp = ApiResponse(200, 'success', 'User deleted successfully.', None)
    resp.set_cookie('auth', newToken, path=ENV.API_ENDPOINT)
    return resp
  except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    return ApiResponse(500, 'fail', 'Internal server error.', None)


def login_user():
  try:
    body = request.json
    if body:
      userReq = User(**body['data'])
      userList = User.objects(identity=str(userReq.identity))  # type: ignore
      if len(userList) == 0:
        return ApiResponse(401, 'fail', 'Wrong authentication.', None)
      user = userList[0]

      if not check_password_hash(str(user.password), str(userReq.password)):
        return ApiResponse(401, 'fail', 'Wrong authentication.', None)

      # Authorization return token
      dataForToken = {
          'identity': user.identity
      }
      token = tokenizer(dataForToken)
      if token is None:
        raise Exception('Token generating error.')
      user.save()

      resp = ApiResponse(
          200, 'success', f'User {user.identity} logged in successfully.', token)
      resp.set_cookie('auth', token, path=ENV.API_ENDPOINT)
      return resp
    else:
      return ApiResponse(400, 'fail', 'Bad request.', None)
  except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    return ApiResponse(500, 'fail', 'Internal server error.', None)


def logout_user():
  try:
    # Authentication check
    auth = request.cookies.get('auth')  # type: ignore
    if auth is None:
      return ApiResponse(401, 'fail', 'Unauthorized, auth is none.', None)
    data = get_data_by_token(str(auth))
    if data is None:
      return ApiResponse(401, 'fail', 'Unauthorized, token is none.', None)
    user, newToken = data
    if user is None:
      return ApiResponse(401, 'fail', 'Unauthorized, user is none.', None)
    if not str(user.role) in ['admin']:
      return ApiResponse(403, 'fail', 'Previlege is forbidden.', None)

    # Deauthentication
    resp = ApiResponse(
        200, 'success', f'User {user.identity} logged out successfully.', None)
    resp.set_cookie('auth', '', path=ENV.API_ENDPOINT)
    return resp
  except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    return ApiResponse(500, 'fail', 'Internal server error.', None)
```

I'm struggle finding way how to keep it simple of every route. Mainly cookie store.

Let me know if you want to know objects or class from my code example.

I think I have really bad design pattern.
Here is my project structure
[image: test]